# Creating KML file with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml

I am not a QGIS expert.

I have to create a kml file to be used as a boundary.

1. I started using qgis with two different shapefiles that feature
2. I separated the polygons of the two shapefiles.
3. I merged the polygons that interested me thus creating two new shapefiles.
4. I converted the two shapefiles into two new kml files.
5. Since I did not succeed in merging the two kml files with qgis, I use an online kml merger and it worked.
6. I reduced the size of the newly merged kml file with qgis simplifying its geometry and then I filled the holes that formed inside the polygon. This kml file is well shown in Google Earth and in qgis.
7. Since I am finding problems in using this new kml file in the site where it should be used as a boundary, I decided to run the geometry check tool
8. the geometry check tool showed that the whole kml file has an invalid geometry (it is red in its entirety).

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Why did you convert to kml and then merged the data?

Comment: Because I did not succeed in correctly merging the two shapefiles with qgis. Maybe it was due to the fact that they have different attributes

Comment: Which tool did you use to merge them?

Comment: I merged the kml files with this online merger: https://kmlmerger.com/

Comment: A person suggested me to edit the polygon since there were some points where two nodes were connnected.

Comment: Have you tried "union" on the two shapefiles of interest and then save them as kml?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I solved this issue editing the polygons since there were some points where two nodes were connected. 
Anyway I have to create a new thread to ask how to merge two shapefiles that have a different attributes tab since with suche files I had to face many problems with qgis